# Min function in objective problem

Tags: optimization

How can I convert this Min function (bold highlighted) in objective problem into simple mathematical equation:

---

Min(x,y)⁡[a[i]*(x[i]-y[i])+ b[i]  **min⁡(x[i], M-c[i])**]
s.t.
c[i]-x[i]+y[i]≤M

here x[i] and y[i] are decision variables.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: It would also be helpful to write the question in a readable way with MathJax : https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Thanks Arnaud and Jose for valuable feedback.